# how to uninstall and reinstall nvidia-drivers (linux 20.04)

Tags: linux, cuda, ubuntu-20.04

I have recently installed ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop and facing some issues running tensorflow1.X-gpu version . The problem is with the installation of cuda, cudnn and nvidia-drivers . I want to use tensorflow 1.15 version which requires cuda 10.0 to be installed . So after going to lot of web scraping , i was finally able to install cuda 10.0 . But now to run cuda 10.0 i needed nvidia-drivers version >= 410. I had pre installed nvidia-drivers 450 , and also while installing cuda , its installed nvidia-drivers - 410.

So i uninstalled nvidia-410 by using : "sudo nvidia-uninstall".

But still nvidia-450 traces are remaining when i use grep command to locate nvidia.

, and i am afraid to use purge command as it can disable my GUI settings. (has happened earlier). Now basically running nvidia-smi command is giving : unable to communicate with nvidia-drivers

So i was wondering if someone can help me out to uninstall and reinstall nvidia-drivers. I am using RTX 2060 graphics card , if thats of any help

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the solution for people who are going through a lot right now to install tensorflow 1.x with gpu support on linux 20.04. So basically the problem was with the kernel version i was using (5.4.0-48-generic) which was not letting  properly install cuda10.0 and cudnn along with tf 1.15. Switching back to kernel version 15.4.0-47-generic resolved the problem for me
This can easily be done in the grub menu during booting time and then for permanent solution u can change the grub file with make grub pick the older version of kernel version .